# Split pdf into separate files based on keywords

Tags: bash, pdf, pdftk

I work in an organization with a Purchasing dept. that processes a lot of POs.  When they "print" a PO job to pdf, the resulting pdf can have pages for one or more Purchase Orders.

For example, the pdf might have 6 pages total but pages 1-2 are for one PO, pages 3-4 are for one PO and pages 5-10 are for a third PO.  Each PO has the words "Purchase Order" on the first page of another PO.

They are wanting to now split previously generated pdfs to have them split so that each pdf is for a separate PO.  Is there a way to use pdftk or similar tool to split pdf based on the keywords "Purchase Order"?  Each pdf after splitting should have only the pages for each PO.  The number of pages per PO vary from PO to PO so I cannot use a standard value like split every 2 pages, this is why the "Purchase Order" words need to be used as a delimeter to know where to split the original pdf.

If anyone has any tips or example script (bash) to help with this, I would be very grateful.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Suggestion: split the PDF apart into its individual pages (`pdftk`). Interate across the set of pages and each time you encounter "_Purchase Order_" in the text (`pdf2text`) for the "current" page, restart a new document. As you loop around the pages, join each page to the current document